# CSS before and after selector inside div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to use after and before selectors to apply certain style to children of a div, my code is as follows :

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 3</a>
    <span class="mid-divider">Some Text</span>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 6</a>
    <span class="last-divider">Some Text</span>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link 9</a>
</div>

.outer-container .mid-divider::before{
    //some styles
}
.outer-container .mid-divider::after{
    //some styles
}
```

I want to apply styles to link1, link2 and link3 as well as to links7,8 and 9. But the selector is not working.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `:before` and `:after` work, you should probably be using `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` instead.

Comment: the meaning of *before* and *after* is not correct for your case.it mean before render and after render the class.not before elements and after elements

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the

> ::before

or

> :: after

tag in this case, just call the elements like this:

> .outer-container a{}
>
> .mid-divider a{}
>
> .last-divider a{}

Comment: You may want to check your selectors; `.mid-divider` and `.last-divider` do not contain any `a` tags in the example and the OP wishes to only style the first 3 and last 3 `a` tags not the middle ones.

Comment: No problem, you can always edit your answer to fix your mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
.outer-container a:nth-child(n+7), .outer-container a:nth-child(-n+3) { }
```

.outer-container a:nth-child(n+7) <-- this selects all children after the 7th child

.outer-container a:nth-child(-n+3) <-- this selects all children before the 4th child.

check this link out. Shows a variety of ways to target different child elements http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: I should also mention that nth-child is a CSS3 excerpt, :nth-of-type is better compatible with legacy browsers